# How to automate to click a button which has no ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

`<div class="add" data-icon="'" ng-show="!editMode" ng-click="btnAdd()"> Add an Honor or Award </div>`
Above is the html code for the button i am trying to click (Add an Honor or Award), but this button doesn't have an unique ID, and keeps on changing the xpath as the user adds multiple data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `css`

```
[class='add'][ng-click='btnAdd()']
```

xpath is also another option

```
//div[contains(.,'Add an Honor or Award')]
```

Or,

```
//div[@class='add']
```